# Como pegar uma hastag no link?

Tags: php

O seguinte link abaixo tem uma "hastag".

Exemplo: `https://site.com.br/noticia/temer-is-dead#1`

Gostaria de pagar esse **`#1`** que está na url.

É possível isso com PHP ou Js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim, é possível.

Com o **PHP** basta utilizar a função **[parse_url](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.parse-url.php)**

```
$url = parse_url("https://site.com.br/noticia/temer-is-dead#1");
echo $url["fragment"];
```

Para capturar a URL, atual, completa com **JS**

```
console.log(window.location.hash.substr(1));
```

Comment: mas no caso, a URL fica na barra de endereço. Sua resposta é valida, vou ver se consigo fazer algo. Obrigado!

Comment: @Léo editei a resposta. Adicionei o código para pegar o fragmento da URL atual com JS. O fragmento não é enviado para o servidor, por não há como pegar com o PHP.

Comment: deu  certo, valeu